# How to add auto-resize components?

Tags: java, swing, layout, components, layout-manager

I'm wondering how I can add (what LayoutManager should I use) to make the app automatically adjust the components to the current size when full screen mode is enabled or even when the frame is stretched.

Currently this is what the application looks like, when you enable full screen mode the components are static.

**UPDATE:** I'm pasting pictures so you can get an idea of what I wrote.

Component layout in IntelliJ: [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlsBp.png)

[image]

The current design in the small window looks ok: [current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWkOm.png)

[image]

Appearance if we enlarge the window (window zooms in, elements are static): [full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euz2M.png)

[image]

So I'd like the components to automatically resize to the current window when fullscreen mode is enabled.

Comment: Choosing a layout manager does not depend on your code but on your design. BorderLayout is best to make components stretch, but how to apply it depends on your design. Would you mind sharing a drawing or mockup on how you want your window to look?

Comment: 1) To expand on the comment of @GalliadII add two images (or ASCII art) showing the GUI at the minimum size and once expanded. The latter to show how extra space should be assigned. 2) Often the trick is to use different layouts for different parts of the one UI. Don't limit it to just one layout. 3) Post a [mre]. All the DB stuff is irrelevant to the component layout. Take out ***everything*** that does not relate to the layout, including action listeners.

Comment: A layout manager is not going to make  `JLabel` text written with a 10 point font jump to using a 16 point font.  That's not how Swing works.  If that's what you want, you'll have to write the code to make that happen yourself.

Comment: @GalliadII Thanks for the reply, I have corrected the question and pasted pictures of how it looks now.

Comment: *"So I'd like the components to automatically resize"* It makes little sense to have text fields or buttons increase in width, and no sense at all for text fields to increase in height. If there is extra width to be had, I'd assign it all to the table. For extra height, increase the height of the table but either keep the heights of the 'left column' components the same or add extra whitespace between the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I suggest the following design:
your mainPanel, that you assigned as contentPane for your frame gets a Borderlayout.
In the North, you put a panel with a label or just a label, with Allignment X to the left.
the West gets a panel I suggest we call WestPanel and the East gets another one, which I call EastPanel.
WestPanel gets a Boxlayout or a Gridlayout. If you use Gridlayout, you can use 2 Grids wide and for each line one grid depth. You then can add all the labels in the left column and the textfields on the right.
Or you can make panels, with Borderlayout, labels to the West, textfields to the east, and pile them with emptyBorders ontop of each other. I suggest using a method for that.

The EastPabel gets a Tabbed Pane inside of it. Each tab can have its own layout manager, depending on what you want it to be in the end.
Does this help you?